# GVIZ on R not loading mm10 from UCSC

Tags: r

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6
```

I am trying to load an ideogram track for the mm10 mouse genome on GVIZ. This always used to work but now is giving me the below error:

```
> itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "mm10", chromosome = "chr5")
```

> Error in value[3L] :
> There doesn't seem to be any chromosome length data available for genome 'mm10' at UCSC or the service is temporarily down.
> In addition: Warning message:
> In value[3L] :
> There doesn't seem to be any cytoband data available for genome 'mm10' at UCSC or the service is temporarily down. Trying to fetch the chromosome length data.

Comment: Try the European mirror site? From the documentation: The Gviz.ucscUrl option controls which URL is being used to connect to UCSC. For instance, one could switch to the European UCSC mirror by calling options(Gviz.ucscUrl="http://genome-euro.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried this: 

itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "mm10", chromosome = "chr5", Gviz.ucscUrl="http://genome-euro.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/")

Still same error:

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  There doesn't seem to be any chromosome length data available for genome 'mm10' at UCSC or the service is temporarily down.
In addition: Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  There doesn't seem to be any cytoband data available for genome 'mm10' at UCSC or the service is temporarily down. Trying to fetch the chromosome length data.

Comment: mm9, hg19, and hg38 all work. Only mm10 shows this error.

Comment: Maybe run the 'options()' call on its own line before the IdeogramTrack() call?

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error. Can you please post the exact command you would type before the IdeogramTrack() call? I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. Using the code `BiocManager::install("Gviz"); library(Gviz); itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "mm10", chromosome = "chr5")` works without issue on my system (R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10); Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit); Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6). Please edit your question to include the exact code you are using.

Comment: @jared_mamrot you are a savior! Thank you so much. Updating R made this work. It's just weird because I used it just 2 days ago on the R version I posted and it worked fine.

Comment: You're welcome - glad you got it sorted - I'll turn my comment into an answer

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to update R and reinstall Gviz via Bioconductor:

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Gviz")
library(Gviz)
itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "mm10", chromosome = "chr5")
```